# What to do when I remake model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to remake a model, I run `rails d model X` and run `rails g model X ...`. However, when I run `rake db:migrate`, it fails and console says 'table X already exists'.

I found that it works if I manually rewrite schema.rb.

Is this a right way? Are there other things to do(ex. to rewrite) when I destroy and create same model?

Comment: You need to do a rollback if you want to change the database. But deleting and re-creating a model seems like a bit of a smell since there's a well-known mechanism that avoids it. What's the usecase for needing to completely delete the model? Manually re-writing `schema.rb` is *definitely* wrong.

Comment: I delete model , for example, when I created model 'user' with "name:string" but later I want to add it "email:string".

Comment: And I'm saying "migrations exist for a reason, why aren't you using them". http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a migration. You don't need to delete your model to add additional data to it. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration

You want to do something like this:

```
rails generate migration AddEmailToUsers email:string # In the command line
```

This generates a file in db/migrations/

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :email, :string
  end
end
```

Then you run `rake db:migrate` and it will update your table

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the db already exists, even though you delete and create the Model. To delete the existing db you could just kill it, by deleting the development.sqlite file in your db folder.

Comment: Note this will destroy all your data (including data from other models)

Comment: Aaagh; why this advice when Rails has a mechanism for updating model functionality? There's zero reason to delete source files etc. to add a simple column.